# How to get transaction information in payment app

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, hce, emv

i recently started learning android programming at my university and as a final project i started developing nfc-hce payment app like Android Pay and/or Apple pay. I live in a small country where non of the nfc payment apps work so i cannot see in real life how it actually works. I was searching and i found about SwipeYours app and it's source code on GitHub and i am using it now to understand the basics of EMV application in mobile payment app. What i have now is commands for APDU select, from known AID card select, GPO command and READ_REC command.

Using my MasterCard PayPass card everyday i found out that the chip is holding my 10 last transactions and my question is now, how does the card gets all the information about transaction. I would like to implement that in my code.

And i know that only banks and card issuers can make such an applications fully functional  because of the key for generating a cryptogram but i am starting an internship next month in one of the major banks as a student developer in my country and i like to have something to show and maybe continue to develop it with their help.

Comment: There are several 100's of pages in the specifications you would have to digest: https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx

Comment: @Henry Thank you, i already started reading today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into [EMV Book 3](https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223) -- *Annex D Transaction Log Information*.

Citing page 170:

> To read the transaction log information, the special device uses the
>   following  steps:
>
> •  Perform Application Selection and retrieve the
>   Log Entry data element  located in the FCI Issuer Discretionary Data.
>   If the Log Entry data element is  not present, the application does
>   not support the Transaction Log function.
>
> •  Issue a GET DATA command
>   to retrieve the Log Format data element.
>
> •  Issue READ RECORD
>   commands to read the Transaction Log records.

You might find some parts of the [javeemvreader](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader) project interesting (classes [LogFormat](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader/blob/f0d5920a94a0dc4be505fbb5dd03a7f1992f82bc/src/main/java/sasc/emv/LogFormat.java), [TransactionLog](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader/blob/f0d5920a94a0dc4be505fbb5dd03a7f1992f82bc/src/main/java/sasc/emv/TransactionLog.java) and method [EMVSession.checkForTransactionLogRecords()](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader/blob/f0d5920a94a0dc4be505fbb5dd03a7f1992f82bc/src/main/java/sasc/emv/EMVSession.java#L1411) where they are used).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, this javaemvreader will probably help me a lot to understand emv contactless transaction flow :)